# Chlorine Fluoride, why not Fluorine Chloride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, halides

Why is Chlorine Fluoride called "Chlorine Fluoride" rather than "Fluorine Chloride"? As I was taught in school that normally that when nonmetal combine with nonmetal then we write the compound with lower atomic number first.

Comment: Think about electronegativities.

Comment: Anionic part is written in the suffix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, with interhalogen compounds (and possibly most of binary inorganic compounds) are named like **"element" "element'ide'"**, where no suffix is used for the electropositive part (eg: sodium, oxygen, nitrogen), and a suffix "ide" is used for the electronegative part (eg: chloride, oxide, nitride, phosphide, carbide).

Regarding $\ce{ClF}$, fluorine is clearly the electronegative atom here. Thus the name would be **Chlorine fluoride**.

Another example of this is from my personal favorite compound, $\ce{O2F2}$

Here, we have subscripts to indicate the number of atoms. In such cases, we add prefixes "di" or "tri" or "tetra" to the name.

$\ce{O2F2}$ would be correctly called as **Dioxygen difluoride**.

Comment: +1 for FOOF. Have a relevant blog link: http://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2010/02/23/things_i_wont_work_with_dioxygen_difluoride

Comment: @DoktorJ I read that article too. FOOF is a pretty interesting compound indeed.

Comment: FOOF is tremendously amazing and terrifying